# g++4.9 -fvtable-verify link error: cannot find vtv_start.o

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++

I am running g++ 4.9.2.0ubuntu1~14.04 (installed from the toolchain ppa: ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test), and I want to use the Virtual Table Verification (VTV) feature (`-fvtable-verify` in [C++ dialect options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)). When I run the command:

```
g++ -fvtable-verify=std -o test test.cpp
```

The linker exits with the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find vtv_start.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtv
```

The same error occurs with g++ 5.1. Any clue what might be wrong? Should I install any additional packages for the VTV to work?

**Update.** Trying to manually install `libvtv` using `apt-get install libvtv0` fails with the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libvtv0 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9-20140406-1ubuntu1) but 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recompiling `gcc` from source with `--enable-vtable-verify` solved the problem.